# Where does the Z80 processor start executing from?

Tags: z80

Strangely I can't find this information anywhere online -- I've thoroughly looked at the datasheet, and I've searched things like "Z80 program counter initial value" -- but I can't find anything!

My question is simply: when the Z80 just turns on, what value does the program counter take? (i.e., what instruction does it start executing from?)

Logically, I'd assume it initialises to 0, but I want to be sure of this.

Comment: IIRC when we ran CP/M on a TRS-80 Model I, it required a hardware mod because there was a 4 k ROM starting at address 0, so the OS couldn't gain control of the hardware.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it starts from Zero - like the Intel 8080, the Z80 descends from.

*Excerpt from Zilog's March 1978 Product Specification (datasheet), page 2, Pin Description, here the `/RESET` signal (emphasis mine):*

> Input, active low. RESET initializes the CPU as follows:
>   reset interrupt enable flip-flop, **clear PC** and registers
>   I and R and set interrupt to 8080A mode.

Similar the description in the 1977 Z80 Technical Manual (03-0029-01) on page 9.

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't know that the 8080 started at zero either, but it makes complete sense.

Comment: Does anything *not* start at zero?

Comment: @dashnick Many don't just start, but take a vector form a predefined location like 6500 and 6800 start at the vector residing at FFFE/FF, 68k takes the initial PC from Vector 1 (address 4..7). Other do start form some address where the IOC locates a loader record, and so on. Starting from Zero is only one of many ways.

Comment: Intels 8086 employs an interesting combination by starting a offset zero, like 8080/Z80, but in segment FFFF, thus at absolute address FFFF0.

Comment: 6502 chip reset starts at a vector found at FFFC.  FFFA and FFFE are for interrupts.    In other words, reset makes a 6502 do `JMP(FFFC)`. But the 6502 requires 0000-01FF be RAM since those are zero page (basically registers) and the stack.

Comment: PDP-11 starts from a location stored at location 50 (octal), if my memory from 40 years ago is to be trusted, or else a bootstrap program starting at that location. We called it the '50-sequence', and often had to enter it from the console toggle switches.

Comment: [173000 for Warm UNIX](http://jdebp.info./FGA/emergency-and-rescue-mode-bootstrap.html#history)

Comment: @user207421, That sinking feeling when... You realize that your buggy program has just overwritten the boot loader. :-O